# Is it a requirement to concatenate multiple 7zip files in Linux before being able to uncompress them?

Tags: linux, 7-zip

I generally use 7zip when on Windows and uncompressing multiple 7zip files. I have come across several articles noting that I need to concatenate multiple 7zip files to a single zip archive if I wish to uncompress in Linux.

1. Is this necessary?
2. Can I not specify simply the first of the multiple 7zip files?

The reason I ask is it appears that when running the command `7zr e {name_of_first_archive}` it only uncompresses the first archive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can extract/decompress 7z split archives, no need to concatenate the parts prior to extraction. The only requirement is that your archives must have incremental extensions of the type *.NNN* (where N=[0..9]) starting from *.001*. This is probably because when you create a split archive using 7z, it will name each part of the archive this way.
Then, all you have to do is run the command on the first archive:

```
[me home]$ ls
diveintopython3.pdf.7z.001  diveintopython3.pdf.7z.002  diveintopython3.pdf.7z.003

[me home]$ 7zr x diveintopython3.pdf.7z.001

7-Zip (A) [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18 p7zip Version 9.20 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,8 CPUs)

Processing archive: diveintopython3.pdf.7z.001

Extracting  diveintopython3.pdf

Everything is Ok

Size:       2598283 Compressed: 734003
```

Comment: This, then, will only work if you are uncompressing one file compressed into multiple archives, not if you want to uncompress multiple, independant archives. Still, I think it is what the OP wanted, so +1.

Comment: True, +1. When uncompressing a multi-part 7z archive created as per the 7z format (.001 etc), the archive itself might contain several files/directories and the file directory and metadata are always in last volume. I don't see how could one extract "independent" archives by passing only the first one as argument.

Comment: @don_crissti - Interesting. I tried that in the first instance and it failed hence the concatenation.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey - If the parts had incremental extensions of type .7z.NNN then 7zip should work, no idea why it failed on your side. On the other hand, terdon's suggestion (and my "shortcut" from the comment on his post) will not work with parts like *.7z.NNN unless you add another wildcard before the closing quote: `7zr x '*.7z*'`. One more thing (after re-reading your post): regardless the number of parts, terminal ouput will only mention the first one when echoing `Processing archive:` then it will jump to `Extracting ...` so _it appears_ it only uncompresses the first archive.

Comment: @don_crissti - I did notice that only the name of the first file is echoed however what concerned me was that it kept prompting me if I wanted to overwrite a file each time it went through the list of available compressed archives.

Comment: @don_crissti - What do you mean by "unless you add another wildcard before the closing quote"

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey What I meant was that if you use terdon's script from his post or my one-liner to decompress split archives (e.g. arch.7z.001, arch.7z.002 etc) you have to add another wildcard before the closing quote otherwise it will not work. So `7zr x '*.7z'` will unpack archives ending in .7z while `7zr x '*.7z*'`will unpack archives ending in .7z.* (like .7z.001 etc)

Answer (score 2):

Well, apparently you can't. Weird, but there you go. This little script will do what you want though (assuming your archives have the extension .7z, if not, change to whatever extension they have) :

```
for n in *7z; do 7zr x $n; done
```

Use the 'x' rather than the 'e' flag because 'e' will extract all files to the current directory while 'x' will preserve the original paths.

To make your life easier, you can add this little function to your ~/.bashrc file:

```
function multi7z () {
    for n in $@; do 7zr x $n; done
}
```

You can then uncompress multiple archives as expected:

```
$ multi7z *7z
```

or

```
$ multi7z a.7z b.7z n.7z
```

EDIT: This will work if you are uncompressing multiple, *independent* archives. If you have *one* archive split across many .7z files, use @don_crissti's answer instead.

Comment: Isn't the above the same as running: `7zr x '*.7z'` ?

Comment: @don_crissti Why, so it is! All that was needed were the quotes! Well spotted.